# Couchbase 3: How to associate JSON document with a type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, couchbase, sql++

I am using Couchbase 3 as a memcache in my ASP.NET project. I would like to give `N1QL` a try. I want to insert some records (along with their expiration time) and then would like to query, on the basis of some JSON property.

I have gone through its documentation, like this:

http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-basics.html

However, I am yet to discover how can I associate my JSON docs with a type.

How can I achieve this? Is there some documentation available?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. A type is usually a String field of your JSON document simply called type.

Comment: Wow, its really simple then. Suppose I miss this `type` property, what happens then?

Comment: Please note that you referred here to the Java documentation, it's quite different in the structure of classes and the conversion to JSON. Anyway - did you solve the issue?

Comment: Actually, there is no such document for .NET APIs. This is the best replacement available: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.1/storing.html. But, I don't get it. It should obviously be specified in docs that what to specify in `N1QL` query's `FROM` clause.

Comment: Well, it's not specific to N1QL, you can have it either way and run Views to filter by type.  In N1QL you can have it or not. It just make your life easier.  Any way please use the newer version of the site with "developer" post fix, which is updated to version 2.2 of the sdks [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/java-2.2/documents-basics.html)